# Where to ask questions about StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I know this is not a great place to ask this question, as is it not about TeX, but ... where do I ask questions about StackExchange? All internet forums use to have a section to discuss and ask questions about the forum itself, but I haven't found such a section on StackExchange (maybe I'm just bad at searching).

The reason I'm wondering this is because I wonder how to subscribe to answers and comments in a question, and how to turn on the option to become subscribed automatically either when you ask a question or when you answer on one or leave a comment on either a question or an answer. Currently, I'm not getting any notifications when I'm getting a reply to anything I have written, but I would like to be notified immediately when someone has replied to something I have written.

Thanks.

Comment: there is a link to the meta site for each stackexchange site at the top of the page

Comment: I flagged the question to be moved to meta. Guess you will see it there soon. `:)`

Comment: @David: Ah, I didn't know that was the place to ask those questions. But now I know, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here.

`\vfill`

(Since I've already figured out how to leave short answers and so have no need to make the joke, I'll try to be a *bit* more useful:)

StackExchange is a network of sites with individual sites related to all sorts of topics from the sublime (TeX) to the ridiculous (Maths).  Each site has it's own "meta" which is where to ask questions about that specific StackExchange site.  There is also a system-wide "meta" for general questions that pertain to all the sites.  Thus if you have a question about the site you should ask yourself if it is specific to this particular StackExchange site or whether you would expect it to be answered by someone knowledgeable about StackExchange sites but not necessarily about this one.

The sites are:

- [Meta-TeX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com)
- [Meta-SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

As always, it's worth doing a bit of searching to see if your question has come up before.  It's also worth noting that the main meta site gets users from all different sites and they have different cultures.  Thick skin can help!

Comment: Thanks! I think the "Questions that may already have your answer" suggestions usually work very well and usually contain some question that is what I'm searching for, so there is where I'm doing my searching :) It didn't work this time, though.

Comment: Rhinoceros' skin might be the thickest. :-)